# Default path when user logs in

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, directory

How can I put a user in a default directory when the logs in via SSH on Ubuntu?  Currently, users are in `~` but I want them in something like `/path/to/something`.  How is this configured?  The machine will always have the path.

Many thanks :).

Comment: Do you mean changing the home directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the users home directory but change the dirextory where they login to then you would have to add a `cd /path/to/something` at the end of the `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the home directory of a user, you can use:

```
$ sudo usermod -d /path/to/new/home username
```